# PHP form file upload: 2 inputs but only attaching 1 file

Tags: php, arrays, forms, file, foreach

I have being trying to figure this out for a while and just can't seem to get it. I have a working code for one file upload which works fine and now trying to create one for 2 uploads. To attempt to add multiple files I have added a foreach loop and switched the name attribute of the form input to name="photo[]" so that it reads an array. The form submits with no errors but I still only receive the first file in the email attachments. I have seen lot's of similar questions but still can't get it- thank you for your patience! (I have also played around with:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
```

in place of and aswell as foreach) but here is my current code.

**HTML Form:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method= "post" action="couple_uploader_test.php"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="myEmail" value="info@website.co.uk"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Couple Portrait Order">
   <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="customerName" required="true"/><br/>
   <label>Email:</label><input type="email" name="customerEmail" required="true"/><br/>
   <label>Photo:</label><input type="file" name="photo[]" accept="image/*" required="true"/>
   <label>2nd Photo (optional):</label><input type="file" name="photo[]" accept="image/*"/>
   <label>Notes:</label><textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="6">customer message here</textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="http://www.website.co.uk/html/couple_uploaded.html"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit Photo"/>
</form>
```

**Uploader PHP:**

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['myEmail'];
$from = $_POST['customerEmail'];
$name = $_POST['customerName'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message']."\n\n" . $name;

$message = wordwrap($message,70);

foreach ($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {

   $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
   $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["photo"]["name"][$key]);
   $extension = end($temp);

   if ((($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$key] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$key] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$key] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$key] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$key] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$key] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"][$key] < 3000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

      /* GET File Variables */ 
      $tmpName = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key]; 
      $fileType = $_FILES['photo']['type'][$key]; 
      $fileName = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key]; 

      /* Start of headers */ 
      $headers = "From: $from"; 

      if (file($tmpName)) { 
        /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
        $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
        $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
        fclose($file); 

        /* a boundary string */
        $randomVal = md5(time()); 
        $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

        /* Header for File Attachment */
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
        $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

        /* Multipart Boundary above message */
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
                   "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
                   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
                   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
                   $message . "\n\n"; 

        /* Encoding file data */
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

        /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
        $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
                  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
                  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
                  $data . "\n\n" . 
                  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
      }
   } else {
     echo "Invalid File.";
   }
}

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($sent) {
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://website.co.uk/html/thankyou.html">';
} else {
    echo "Sorry, we have encoutered a problem sending your message. Please try again or get in     touch via the contact page";
}

?>
```

Ideally I need it to loop through 2 input file types (the second one being optional so if a user just uploads one image it will still work) and attach them to one single email. Thank you.

Comment: If you cannot be bothered to format you code in a readable fashion, why should we bother reading it?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what you're after. (It looks readable to me) This is my first post and I am stuck so I just copied in my code as I have it so far so we can try figure out what is wrong with it - I'm very much a novice

Comment: It works for me. Remove the meta refresh, and let's echo the name of your file. Exactly what doesn't works?

Comment: So I guess I have to do it!

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what you really received? You're also simply assuming uploads will never fail. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason. Plus... `file()` reads the entire file into an array, and then you throw away the array. That is hideously inefficient. why not just `is_readable($file)` or whatever?

Comment: It runs fine but when the email comes through it only brings the first file upload instead of 2 attachments. I was originally trying to redirect using header(Location: ...) but it kept throwing up errors. Is there a better way to get to next page? I am calling the PHP from a separate file as the only purpose I need it for is to process the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `$headers` and `$message` to outside of your `for` loop. You already have `$message` outside, but you are overwriting it with this code:

```
 /* Multipart Boundary above message */
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
               "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
               "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
               $message . "\n\n";
```

It should be:

```
 /* Multipart Boundary above message */
    $message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
               "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
               "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
               $message . "\n\n";
```

PS: You can redirect in PHP like so:

```
 header('Location: http://website.co.uk/html/thankyou.html');
```

Another PS: You should secure against errors by checking things are set in the `$_POST` array before trying to access them like so:

```
 $to = isset($_POST['myEmail']) ? $_POST['myEmail'] : NULL;
```

This is a ternary operator, which is basically shorthand for:

```
 if(isset($_POST['myEmail'])) {
   $to = $_POST['myEmail']
 } else {
   $to = NULL;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When your loop runs it rewrite both the $message and the $headers variables from scratch instead of concatenating. So when you actually send the email the attached file is only one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the foreach loop correctly to get each uploaded file one at a time so you can process it, you would end up with something like this.

I have not checked the actual contents of header are correct I just assumed you had it right, but I did simplify some of the coding and remove the unnecessary creation of scalar variables to hold data that was already there in the $_FILES array in a perfectly usable state.

```
/* a boundary string */
$randomVal = md5(time()); 

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $from"; 

$mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

/* Header for File Attachment */
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

/* Multipart Boundary above message */
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
           "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
           "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
            $message . "\n\n"; 

foreach ($_FILES['photo'] as $filenumber => $file) {

   $temp = explode(".", $file["name"]);
   $extension = end($temp);

   if ( ($file["type"] == "image/gif"
      || $file["type"] == "image/jpeg"
      || $file["type"] == "image/jpg"
      || $file["type"] == "image/pjpeg"
      || $file["type"] == "image/x-png"
      || $file["type"] == "image/png" )
    && $file["size"]  < 3000000
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
   {

      if ( file($file['tmp_name']) ) { 
        /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
        $fh = fopen($file['tmp_name'],'rb'); 
        $data = fread($fh,filesize($file['tmp_name'])); 
        fclose($fh); 

        /* Encoding file data */
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

        /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
        $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
                  "Content-Type: {$file['type']};\n" . 
                  " name=\"{$file['name']}\"\n" . 
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
                  $data . "\n\n" . 
                  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
      }
   } // endif
} // endforeach
```